# StrutsSpringTestCase - getActionMapping() - Does it search for actions in struts.xml?

Tags: java, spring, junit, struts2, unit-testing

I am trying to write test for Struts2 action by extending `StrutsSpringTestCase`. The reference:  [Unit Testing](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/unit-testing.html).

When I call `getActionMapping(<action url>)`, does it search `struts.xml` file for the action mapping?

**The Code:**

```
ActionMapping mapping = getActionMapping("/custSeach.action");// Intentionally missed 'r'.
assertEquals("custSeach", mapping.getName());
```

This passes. But there is no `custSeach` action in my `struts.xml` mapping.

**More details:**

`struts.xml`  is in the class path. I could print all files loaded from the classpath and `struts.xml` is one of them.

also, I tried the following as well:

```
ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("custSearch");
assertNotNull(proxy);
```

`custSearch` does exist. But it's still throwing the error

```
There is no Action mapped for action name custSearch.
```

Comment: Seems like you have your answer already. You ask a lot of *strange* questions without giving any response. What is the purpose of it?

Comment: I guess you wanted more details. Happy to provide, though. But the question is ` does it search struts.xml file for the action mapping?` I don't know the answer for it yet. :-) and it does not seem to work.

Comment: @AleksandrM provided some more details. Not sure what other details you want.

Comment: You forgot about namespace in your second example.

Comment: @AleksandrM there is no namespace name. Its default, which is "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Th first method returns a *mapping to try*, it doesn't guarantee that this action will be executed.

The `struts.xml` files is parsed on startup to create a run-time configuration, so it has less meaning to this method which is actually uses [`ActionMapper`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/mapper/ActionMapper.html) that could have different implementation.

The second method does actually returns the action config (if no exception is thrown), so the action can be executed.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to find out if struts.xml is loaded? Please check my edit. It throws There is no action mapped.

Comment: It's loaded by default if exists. If you have a specific question, please, ask it separately. This answer I have written against your last edit.